# Flask - 404 URL was not found

Tags: python, flask, http-status-code-404

When I run my code I get a 404 error.
I tried to add
`app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = '127.0.0.1:500-'`
but it didn't help.
This is such a basic Flask app, I don't understand what the problem could be.
I have another flask project that works perfect, but for some reason,
the routes aren't working.
Anyone have an idea what could possibly be going wrong?

Here's my code.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

app.route('/')
def index():
    return ""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use `@` for the decorator. Below should work

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return ""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Wow I'm so blind. Thank you!

Comment: Great, can you mark the answer as accepted?